# In Chrome Extension's manifest, Is it possible to define update_url outside of the extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In my scenario, I have a Chrome extension that is self hosted, and would like to specify the update_url outside of the extensions for flexibility.

Is there a way to specify the update URL outside of the manifest, or even outside of the extension (for example, in the registry, or chrome storage area)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/), you have to provide an update URl on the manifest, and that manifest can't be altered in runtime for security reasons.
What you can do is provide an update url that and change de target XML as you need on your server. It can also be a redirect link, for example.